# SP2010 - Visual Web Part - Storing metadata in folders in document libraries

Tags: development, caml-query, visual-web-part, caml, metadata

I want to store a number to folders to enforce ordering.
I noticed these three pages

[Get Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.getproperty.aspx)

[Set Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.setproperty.aspx)

[Add Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.addproperty.aspx)

And I want to know if it's possible to use these to add a number to the folder, and then in a CAML query, get the folders ordered by this property?